# Laravel4, eager loading is not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get "reviews" from my database where the user is from MX (for example) so, I have this:

```
Review::with(array('user' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('country_code', '=', 'MX');
}))
->with('user.country','pictures')
->where('shop_id',Input::get('id'))
->orderBy('id','DESC'))
->get()
->toArray()
```

But seems to be like **where('country_code', '=', 'MX')** is not taken into account because retrieve all reviews and I just want the reviews written by the user from MX.

- **user** and **picture** inside **with** are functions within my User model
- country_code is a field from users table

The goal is: Just get the reviews written by a user from the country specified, and was testing something like this:

```
Review::where('shop_id',Input::get('id'))
->with('user.country','pictures')
->where('users.country_code','MX')
->orderBy('id','DESC'))
->get()
->toArray()
```

But is not working as well because says: Unknow column users.country_code in where....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a query that filters based on the relation. Eager loading constraints only constrain the records that come with your main result set.

```
Review::whereHas('users', function ($q)
{
    $q->where('country_code', 'MX');
})
->with('user','pictures')
->where('shop_id',Input::get('id'))
->orderBy('id','DESC'))
->get();
```

The whereHas is saying ... give me only Reviews that have a User with `country_code=MX`.

**Reference**

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Comment: Is true, is working now.. just change whereHas('users' to whereHas('user'...  Thank you :)

Comment: can a review have more than 1 user ?

Comment: Nope just 1 user, and the 'user' of whereHas is the name of the function within my Review model.

Comment: @lagbox Why are you doing this ->with('user','pictures') should not it be ->with('pictures') only? Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to write in my post that I'm using ->with('user.country','pictures)... because the function user within  Review model have another ->with('country') to get the country details of each user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want reviews written by a certain user or group of users you don't want to use eager loading. Try this:

```
Review::with(array('user', 'pictures'))
    ->join('users', 'reviews.user_id', '=', 'users.id)
    ->where('users.country_code', '=', 'MX')
    ->where('reviews.shop_id', Input::get('id'))
    ->orderBy('reviews.id', 'DESC'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you anyway, but I'm not using joins directly instead I'm using relationships with models.